# How to display Text just next to the Text Box using jQuery in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the Pop up window to enter the value of "Subject" field and this field is mandatory, So how to display the Text just next to the "Subject" field without using validation and using just simple jQuery, i.e. "Please enter the Subject". The below code is working but if I want  to add another Subject for some Task then the Text "Please enter the Subject" is shown on that pop up. So how to remove it.

```
if ($("#subject").val().length > 0)
{
      $.ajax({
                    url: '/Task/QuickSave',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $('form#quickSaveTask').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('data');
                    }
                });
                $('#Subject').val('');
                $('#lean_overlay').fadeOut();
                $('#Add').hide();
                if (refreshTaskGrid != '') refreshTaskGrid();
                return false;
}
else
{
          var msg = $('#subject-message');
            if (msg.length == 0) {
                msg = $('<div id="subject-message"></div>')
                $('#subject').after(msg);
            }
            $("#subject").focus();
            msg.html('Please enter the Subject !');   
            return false;
}
msg.html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the below code will help

```
$('text-box').change(function(){
    var textEntered=$(this).val();

    if(textEntered.length>0){
        //construct logic to show message 
        if($('#msg-container').size()==0)
        {
             $('<div id="msg-container">Please enter message</div>').css('float','left').appendTo($(this));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //remove the message div
        $('#msg-container').remove();
    }
});
```